# Si può usare "fare" nel senso di "trasmettere/mettere in onda"?

Tags: verbs, grammar

1-Su quel canale fanno un programma molto interessante.

Al posto di "mandare in onda" o "trasmettere" si potrebbe usare dare, che trova anche riscontro su vari dizionari:

2-Su quel canale danno un programma molto interessante.

L'uso di "fare" (di cui non trovo riscontri nei dizionari per questo significato) è molto colloquiale, ma è corretto da un punto di vista strettamente grammaticale?

Answer (score 2):

Prima di tutto: dici “da un punto di vista strettamente grammaticale”, ma la grammatica qui non c'entra molto (la grammatica riguarderebbe, per esempio, se usare “fanno” o “facciano” o cos'altro): è una questione di lessico.

Entrando nel merito, il verbo “fare” ha un senso così generico che va bene quasi ovunque. Per esempio, [la prima definizione che ne dà il vocabolario Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fare2), prima di passare ad accezioni più specifiche, è proprio:

> Verbo di sign. generico: può esprimere qualsiasi azione, materiale o no, specificata meglio dal complemento: *f. un passo, un gesto, un movimento, un salto, una risata, un urlo, un sospiro, uno sbadiglio, un lamento; f. una buona azione, un lavoro, un progetto, un vóto; f. un pensiero, un sogno; f. uno scherzo a qualcuno; f. il solletico*. Con sign. anche più ampio: *non so che f. stasera; che cosa fai lì tutto solo?*

E, più avanti, anche: “Compiere, eseguire, attuare: *f. un balletto, una scoperta, un’invenzione, un ritrovamento, un esame; f. una guerra*.” Quindi è difficile che ci sia qualcosa, da un pensiero a una guerra, che non si possa fare. E empiricamente, visto che – in prima approssimazione – una lingua è data dal modo in cui la usano i parlanti, puoi vedere che espressioni come “cosa fanno stasera in tv” suonano normalissime e sono molto diffuse (con migliaia di risultati su Google, per quel che vale).

Altro discorso è quello dei registri linguistici, come accenni tu stesso menzionando il fatto che “fare” è qui usato in modo colloquiale. In un italiano più formale, più ricercato, non è desiderabile usare troppo spesso termini generici come appunto “fare” o “cosa”, e si può preferire l'uso di termini specifici come, nel caso in questione, “trasmettere”.